# SSIS: Pass connection string as an argument in an Execute Process task?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I use a dtsConfig file that holds the actual connections.

I am working with the Execute Process task and the executable that the task calls needs 2 of the connection strings from the dtsConfig file.  Is there a way for me to pass these connection string values as an argument in the task?

I have not found a way to do this so inside the executable I load the dtsConfig file as an XmlDocument and look for the connections that I need.

Is there any other way?

Oh, I cannot use a Script task/component as this has to run on both SQL 2008R2 and SQL 2012.  SQL 2012 can't upgrade packages with Script components during execution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the dtsConfig definition to set the Connection String in a Variable.

Within each package you can use that variable as an Expression to override the ConnectionString property of the Data Connection.

You can pass variables to sub-packages or processes.